# Is simple_list_item_single_choice the default layout for ListPreference items?

Tags: android, android-resources, listpreference

I replicated the `ListPreference` code into my own custom ListPreference and created an `ArrayAdapter<>` for the list, which inflates simple_list_item_single_choice in `getView()`
But I get a list with short rows, as opposed to the original ListPreferences which has taller rows.

Am I using the wrong layout resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the default layout is for ListPreference.

```
android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice
```

I always forget that the source code I cannot see in Eclipse is always available at the
[GrepCode site](http://grepcode.com/search/?query=android)
I traced the source code for [AlertParams in AlertController](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/com/android/internal/app/AlertController.java#AlertController.AlertParams) and there I found what the dialog.mSingleChoiceItemLayout field was.

Comment: But it looks different from the standard `ListPreference` dialog!

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be to create your own layout for each cell from simple_list_item_single_choice layout, specifying a padding (top and bottom) in the parent container so that you have a taller cell. Obviously you would have to update in your adapter the reference to the layout you want to use for the cell.

Comment: You are right, of course, but I want to use the same system resource that ListPreference (or its parents) use to form the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can view the source code of Android directly in Eclipse. Here you have a nice tutorial on how to do it ;)

**[Attaching Android platform source in Eclipse](http://android.opensourceror.org/2010/01/18/android-source/)**

Comment: Thanks, but that blog is from 2010, since then Eclipse has improved. At least for the last 3 versions it includes the android sources and when it does not find them it has a button to select the sources directory. Some inner classes are still not there, `AlertController` is one of the missing classes, that's why I went to grepcode.